# How to Give an Elliptical Border a Braided Effect

Tags: tikz-pgf, border, braids

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{cadmiumgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.42, 0.235} % 0, 107, 60
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \clip (0,0) ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm);
            
            \draw[line width=5pt,Gold,fill=cadmiumgreen!93.5] ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm); 
            \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.37,clip, trim = 0 0 0 0]{example-image-a}};
            \draw[line width=10.5pt,Gold] ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the image

[image]

QUESTION: I would like to give the gold border a braided effect. Does anyone know how this might be accomplished?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly a combination two paths with the `snake` decoration and the `spath3`/`braids`/`knots` libraries but I don't think it's that straight forward.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: `snake` is annoying. I think it is better to use a parametrized plot of an ellipse, say `({xr*(1+.1*sin(\x*40))*cos \x}, {yr*(1+.1*sin(\x*40))*sin \x})` where `xr` and `yr` are the radii and `\x` is the angle (from 0 to 360). This gives you two wavey ellipses at least. Putting these as `\strand`s however doesn't seem to lead to the desired result. Either it's too many points or the closed path don't work so nicely with `knots`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

I don't know what you mean by "braided effect".  I made a wild guess: something like an old picture frame.  But details can be changed...

I define a decoration, mainly, taking two arguments: the number of steps (of the effect) and the width of the line to which the decoration is applied.  Both are used as dimensions in points afterwards.

**Remark** It works better with closed curves.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\definecolor{CadmiumGreen}{RGB}{0, 107, 60}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228, 168, 53}
\definecolor{DarkGold}{RGB}{221, 137, 53}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  braid/.style 2 args={% nb of steps, width in pts
    preaction={draw=DarkGold, line width=#2pt},
    decoration={%
      markings,
      mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1/#1 with {
        \tikzmath{%
          \dl = \pgfdecoratedpathlength/#1;
          {
            \draw[DarkGold, line width=#2/13 pt, fill=Gold,
            rounded corners=5pt, rotate=-40]
            (.4*\dl pt, 0) rectangle ++(.7*\dl pt, .8*#2 pt);
            \draw[DarkGold, line width=#2/10 pt, fill=Gold,
            rounded corners=3pt, rotate=20]
            (0, -.3*#2 pt) rectangle ++(\dl pt -1pt, .7*#2 pt);
          };
        }
      }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  }  
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[Gold, fill=CadmiumGreen, line width=10pt, braid={60}{12}]
  ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this fine answer!

Answer (score 21):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
line width=8.3pt,
declare function={
rx=4.25;
ry=5.5;
n=10;
da=180/n;
ex1=(rx+0.2*cos(n*\t))*cos(\t);
ey1=(ry+0.2*cos(n*\t))*sin(\t);
ex2=(rx+0.2*cos(n*\t+120))*cos(\t);
ey2=(ry+0.2*cos(n*\t+120))*sin(\t);
ex3=(rx+0.2*cos(n*\t+240))*cos(\t);
ey3=(ry+0.2*cos(n*\t+240))*sin(\t);
},
samples=10, smooth, variable=\t,
]
\fill[teal] ellipse[radius=rx, y radius=ry];
\foreach \i [parse=true] in {0,...,(2*n-1)}{
\draw[orange!95!black] plot[domain=(\i-3/3)*da:(\i+0/3)*da+0.2] (ex1,ey1);
\draw[orange!85!black] plot[domain=(\i-2/3)*da:(\i+1/3)*da+0.2] (ex2,ey2);
\draw[orange!75!black] plot[domain=(\i-1/3)*da:(\i+2/3)*da+0.2] (ex3,ey3);
}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (rx,-ry);
\foreach \i [parse=true] in {(2*n)}{
\draw[orange!95!black] plot[domain=(\i-3/3)*da:(\i+0/3)*da+0.2] (ex1,ey1);
\draw[orange!85!black] plot[domain=(\i-2/3)*da:(\i+1/3)*da+0.2] (ex2,ey2);
\draw[orange!75!black] plot[domain=(\i-1/3)*da:(\i+2/3)*da+0.2] (ex3,ey3);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ellipse with braided frame]
[image: Ellipse with tightly braided frame]

Comment: +1 Many thanks for posting this.

Comment: I can only say that TSE users are so fantastic!

Answer (score 14):

Here's an alternative in [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) using a routine I wrote earlier that draws any path as a rope (sort of).

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef rope expr c =  % c is a circular path...
    save s, w, n, a, b, A; 
    numeric s, w, n, A; 
    w = -1; n = -1; A = arclength c; s = A/floor(A/2);
    path a[]; 
    for t=0 step s until A + 1:
        a[incr n] = (0,+w) rotated angle direction arctime t-3/2s of c of c shifted point arctime t-3/2s of c of c
                 .. (0,+w) rotated angle direction arctime t-1/2s of c of c shifted point arctime t-1/2s of c of c
                 .. (0,-w) rotated angle direction arctime t+1/2s of c of c shifted point arctime t+1/2s of c of c
                 .. (0,-w) rotated angle direction arctime t+3/2s of c of c shifted point arctime t+3/2s of c of c;
    endfor
    image(
        for i=1 upto n:
            path b; b = buildcycle(a[i-1], reverse a[i]);
            fill b withcolor 1/2[white, gold]; 
            draw b withpen pencircle scaled 1/8 withcolor gold;
        endfor
    )
enddef;

color gold, cadium_green; 
gold = 1/256(228, 168, 72);
cadium_green = 1/256(0, 107, 60);

beginfig(1);

    path frame; frame = fullcircle scaled 5cm xscaled 17/22;
    fill frame withcolor cadium_green;
    draw rope frame;
    label("\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}", origin);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Adjust the value of `w` to make the rope thicker, and to flip between cable-laid and hawser-laid.  `-1` gives you a good looking cable (which is usually used for decoration), `1` gives the other direction. `-2` looks a bit fatter.

Comment: +1 Thank you for posting this answer.